# Is it a good/bad practice to combine Robotframework keywords and page objects?

Tags: robotframework

So I have this case where I want to combine the keywords files with the page objects files.

Let's assume I have `foo.robot` for keywords and `bar.robot` for page object:

---

```
#foo.robot
*** Settings ***
Ressource  bar.robot

*** Keywords ***
Click Submit Button
   Wait Untile Element Is Visible  ${variable_from_bar}  60s
   Click Button                    ${variable_from_bar}
```

---

```
#bar.robot
*** Variables ***
${variable_from_bar}               //button[@id="dummybutton"]
```

---

my idea is to combine them both like this

```
#foobar.robot

*** Variables ***
${variable_from_bar}               //button[@id="dummybutton"]

*** Keywords ***
Click Submit Button
   Wait Untile Element Is Visible  ${variable_from_bar}  60s
   Click Button                    ${variable_from_bar}
```

Is there any particular reason why I shouldn't do this practice? Or any technical issue that would face me in the future after applying it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally I would suggest to rename `.robot` to `.resource` so resource files will be distinguished from suite files in naming as well.

As for the combination I think it is not a bad approach but the hierarchy can be a bit more separated. Let's say there are web elements that are used across multiple pages you want to put those into separate resource files independent from the page object resource file.

Let's say there is a unique button.

button.resource

```
*** Keywords ***
Click Unique Button
    [Arguments]    ${button_locator}
    # Handle some unique behaviour
    Click Button    ${button_locator}
```

This could be used across multiple pages where the purpose of the button is different, the ID different but still the way a button click should be handled is the same.

PageA.resource

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    button.resource

*** Variables ***
${variable_from_bar}               //button[@id="dummybutton"]

*** Keywords ***
Do Stuff
    Click Unique Button    ${variable_from_bar}
```

PageB.resource

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    button.resource

*** Variables ***
${download_file}               //button[@id="downloadbutton"]

*** Keywords ***
Do Stuff
    Select File    my_file.txt
    Click Unique Button    ${download_file}
```

To summarize you could merge the page object keywords and locator variables into the same file but you should keep the generic, page independent keywords in their own resource files.

Comment: yes i do agree with that, i also have some common components like topbar sidebar, loader ext..., thank you for stating that, so there is no negative effect that i might get other than this?

Comment: @SaïdTahali I do not know your application but generally I would say no.